# Configurable product isn't displaying in categories?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have an issue where items are not displaying in there categories, sale for example, and I am wondering if it has anything to do with the configurable product quantity which is zero, although the simple products it contains have quantities?

ss-2018-24 contains the following:
ss-2018-24-s (qty 1)
ss-2018-24-m (qty 2)
ss-2018-24-l (qty 2)

ss-2018-24 inventory has the following settings:
Manage Stock - Yes (use config settings: tick)
Enable Qty Increments - No (use config settings: tick)
Enable Qty Increments - Yes

Is the fact that the configurable product has a quantity of zero, the reason the product isn't displaying under the sale category, even though it's assigned?

Some help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Did you set configurable product is in stock to yes?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, just to confirm, stock is set to yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES. It has everything to do with the configurable product quantity being set to zero while also configured to **manage stock**.

By default, **Manage Stock** is turned off for a configurable product, because the inventory is managed through each associated product. This means that you should not set `manage stock` to `yes` for the configurable product itself; only the associated simple products.

Your items are not showing up in the catalog because you have a quantity of `0` configured for a product that you are `managing stock` on. This results in the product not being displayed, because you have indicated there are `0` of them.

*Magento Documentation: https://docs.magento.com/m1/ee/user_guide/catalog/inventory-configurable-product.html*

Answer (score 0):

when we create configurable products then after creating its associated simple products then its does not show under its respected categories so it may be the cause of not re-indexed.So re-indexed from admin then check again.

Re-indexing steps:

Go to admin System > Index Management.See below screen shot.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, site is definitely reindexed